# Open source проект

Tags: java, opensource

Доброго времени суток!

Мне очень хотелось бы принять участие в open source проекте на java.
Может, кто-нибудь знает такие проекты?
Если не сложно, скиньте, пожалуйста, ссылки.
Спасибо :)

Comment: я думаю, ник зачетный

Comment: я тоже заинтересовался этим вопросом

Comment: [https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core](allure). Там хорошо относятся к PR, настроен CI и есть что поделать.

Answer (score 2):

Частным образом, могу предложить тот, в котором я участвовал. Ребята из России (и не только) пилят форумно-блоговый движок http://wiki.jtalks.org/display/jtalks/How+to+join+us

Более глобально - любые популярные фреймворки/библиотеки. Можно [поискать](https://github.com/search?l=Java&o=desc&q=language%3AJava&ref=advsearch&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) на гитхабе по языку и популярности.